# Creating a CAAS using Kubernetes/Docker/Flannel/etcd

Tags: docker, openshift, kubernetes

I would like to request some expert opinion from SMEs on:

1. What would it take to build a CAAS using physical/bare-metal servers.

   a) Suggested options to implement concerns like : Resource Monitoring, Utilization etc

   b) Any suggested approaches to make a robust, scalable, resilient underlying infrastructure which marries well kubernetes/docker/etcd/flannel based CAAS layer

[image]

2. Kubernetes as a solution likes to leverage underlying "Cloud Provider" ; any suggestion to create it from scratch? (of course I am not looking at elaborate solutions like OpenStack, since the idea is to create a lean/low-cost/light-weight solution) The solution I am looking for is to create an IAAS out of lets say 10 prod servers. Not looking for Data Center type of solutions.

Comment: Any suggestions/feedbacks?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you should check out the [Getting started from Scratch](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch.html) guide in the Kubernetes docs.

Comment: Oh yes, I already create a 1 Master - 4 Node cluster (with docker, k8s, flannel, skyDNS, etc) for testing the features. My question is around, how would someone manage this kind of underlying infrastructure in production like environments (1) Resource Utilization (2) Monitoring  etc

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented similar setup on baremetal.

1. you dont need etcd on each machine
2. setup 3 node etcd cluster for high availability
3. if you have space machines then keep etcd cluster separated from controle plane
4. setup 3 node control plane
5. use nginx for load balancing the masters/control plane
6. Run keepalived service on each control plane.
7. The virtual ip should be routable in the across the nodes in cluster. chose VIP from same subnet
8. keepalived provide failover in case primary control plance/master is down